# how to change my router public IP address

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, vpn, nat

I'd like my router to have a different public IP network so I tried rebooting, restarting and my operator's support told me that I can try leaving the router off for 4 days, but I'm not sure if this is going to change anything.

I'd like to know what free solutions I can use to do this:

- maybe I can use a proxy server?
- or a VPN?

but I'm not sure which ones or how to set them up.

Also, there is other way to change it, I'm open to more suggestions.

Comment: You can change IP address by unplugging the router. However, you ISP providers said you need 4 days. This maybe relate to your local ISP vendor's policy.  You can try to connect your computer to the network without router. And then use the command "ipconfig/release " and  "ipconfig/renew" to get a new IP address. Later, you can use this new IP address for your router.

Comment: thanks @Peter.G I'm not sure I can connect my PC directly to the network because it's an optical fiber router...so I don't think I can, right?

Comment: What's your outer problem? Why do you want to change your router's public IP address? It's not possible to tell whether solutions we would suggest will accomplish what you really want without knowing what you really want. For example, proxy servers don't change your router's public IP address. You list them as a possible solution which means what you really want to do isn't change your router's public IP address but something else. But you don't tell us what.

Answer (score 2):

The general answer isthat you can't just change your router's IP address. You may force your router to reconnect, and restarting the router includes a reconnect, but the router will just again request an IP address from your provider.

That your provider's support suggested turning off the router indicates that they think it is possible for you to get a different address, but the fact that they suggested four days indicates that they are either guessing or that is the time until their server discards the IP address assignment.

- You can use a proxy server. The effect of this will be that whatever server you connect to will see the address of this proxy server. Your next question will probably be how to switch the address of the proxy server. You do that by selecting another proxy server.
- You can use a VPN server. Although technically this is different, regarding the IP address the effects are similar to the proxy server.

If you want to change your address because your current address has exceeded some quota on a free service, chances are that the addresses of the proxy or VPN server have already been used for this service and the quota is already exceeded before your first try.

Comment: any suggestion to set up the proxy or the VPN? It'd be great if they are open source. thanks!

Comment: If *you* set up a proxy or VPN server, it will have your IP address. You don't just need software, you need someone who will provide a machine running this software for you. Typically they would want money to provide that service.

Answer (score 0):

1. Save MAC of router
2. Change router MAC to computer MAC
3. Router should automatically reboot
4. Reboot it from gateway
5. Give 5-10 mins for new IP